# sql count/sum the number of calls until a specific date in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum, conditional-statements

I have data that shows the customer calls. I have columns for customer number, phone number(1 customer can have many), date record for each voice call and duration of a call. Table looks lie below example.

```
CusID |  PhoneNum   |  Date             | Duration
20111    43576233   20.01.2016-14:00     00:10:12
20111    44498228   14.01.2016-15:30     00:05:12
20112    43898983   14.01.2016-15:30
```

What I want is to count the number of call attempts for each number before It is answered(Duration is > 0). So that I can estimate how many time I should call on average to reach a customer or phone number. It should basically count any column per phone number before min(Date) where duration is >0.

```
SELECT Phone, Min(Date) FROM XX WHERE Duration IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Phone --
```

I think This should give me the time limit until when I should count the number of calls. I could not figure out how to finish the rest of the job

EDIT- I will add an example

[image]

And the result should only count row number 5 since it is the call before the customer is reached for the first time. So resulted table should be like :

[image]

Comment: How do you want to handle multiple (successful) calls per day?

Comment: I am not interested in succesfull calls. I am trying to find out how many unsuccessfull calls have been made until the first successfull call per phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step is valid:

```
    SELECT
        CusID
        ,PhoneNum
        ,MIN(Date) AS MinDate
    FROM XX
    WHERE Duration IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CusID, PhoneNum
```

This gives you one row per `PhoneNum` with the date of the first successful call.

Now join this to original table and leave only those rows that have a prior date (per `PhoneNum`). Group it by `PhoneNum` again and count. The join should be `LEFT JOIN` to have a row with zero count for numbers that were answered on the first attempt.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        CusID
        ,PhoneNum
        ,MIN(Date) AS MinDate
    FROM XX
    WHERE Duration IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CusID, PhoneNum
)
SELECT
    CusID
    ,PhoneNum
    ,COUNT(XX.PhoneNum) AS Count
FROM
    CTE
    LEFT JOIN XX
        ON  XX.PhoneNum = CTE.PhoneNum
        AND XX.Date < CTE.MinDate
GROUP BY CusID, PhoneNum
;
```

If a number was never answered, it will not be included in the result set at all.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT phonecalls.CusID, COUNT(0) AS failedcalls, phonenumber, success.firstsuccess FROM phonecalls, 
(SELECT min(Date) AS firstsuccess, CusID, phonenumber FROM phonecalls WHERE Duration IS NOT NULL GROUP BY CusID, phonenumber) success
WHERE phonecalls.CusID = success.CusID AND phonecalls.phonenumber = success.phonenumber AND phonecalls.Date < success.firstsuccess
GROUP BY phonecalls.CusID, phonecalls.phonenumber, success.firstsuccess;
```

I've not tested it...

Note: users which have not established a successfull call are not listed. Is this ok, or do you need them listed as well? If so, you need to "left join":

```
    SELECT phonecalls.CusID, COUNT(0) AS failedcalls, phonenumber, success.firstsuccess FROM phonecalls LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT min(Date) AS firstsuccess, CusID, phonenumber FROM phonecalls WHERE Duration IS NOT NULL GROUP BY CusID, phonenumber) success ON 
phonecalls.CusID = success.CusID AND phonecalls.phonenumber = success.phonenumber AND phonecalls.Date < success.firstsuccess
GROUP BY phonecalls.CusID, phonecalls.phonenumber, success.firstsuccess;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use the following logic:

- Assign the number of "unanswered" calls to each row in the data.  This uses conditional aggregation with a window function.
- Then, take the maximum of the count for *answered* calls for each user.
- Count the number of answered calls.
- The ratio is the average.
- This ignores strings of unanswered calls not followed by an answered call.

The resulting query:

```
select phone, max(cume_unanswered), count(*) as num_answered,
       max(cume_unanswered) * 1.0 / count(*) as ratio
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when duration is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by phone order by date) as cume_unanswered
      from t
     ) t
where duration is not null
group by phone;
```

Comment: If I get it right I think this code will provide me the ratio of unanswered calls to answered calls. What I want is to find the unanswered calls until the first answered call. I am not interested in the calls unanswered or answered that have been made after the first answered call. I have added some excel tables to my first question in order to be more clear

Comment: @Zeir . . . This counts the number of unanswered calls before *each* answered call for a phone number.  That seems to be what you want.  If a phone only has one answered call then the two measures are the same.

Comment: i am trying to find number of unanswered calls before first answered call. Not each. You can check the result for phone number 118 at my question.