# T-SQL: Count number of failures until first success

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, analytics, vertica

I have a DB consisting of events with timestamps:

```
row eventName taskName timestamp userName
1   fail      ABC      10.5      John
2   fail      ABC      18.0      John
3   fail      ABC      19.0      Mike
4   fail      XYZ      21.0      John
5   fail      XYZ      23.0      Mike
6   success   ABC      25.0      John
7   fail      ABC      26.0      John
8   success   ABC      28.0      John
```

I'd like to count the number of failures until the first success, per user (and average, but that's beyond this question).

In the example above, John attempted task ABC 2 times (rows 1 & 2) until succeeding (row 6). Subsequent failures and successes can be ignored.

I think I could achieve this by counting the number of rows with "ABC" and "fail" whose timestamp is earlier than the earliest timestamp in all rows with "ABC" and "success", grouping by userName. How do I express this in T-SQL? Specifically, Vertica.

This seemed to be very similar to the case here:
[sql count/sum the number of calls until a specific date in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551595/sql-count-sum-the-number-of-calls-until-a-specific-date-in-another-column)

But when I tried to adapt the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39594686/4354459 as below, I think I got something wrong because I keep getting larger counts than expected.

```
WITH
Successes
AS
(
    SELECT
        events.userName
        ,events.taskName
        ,MIN(events.timestamp) AS FirstSuccessTime
    FROM events
    WHERE events.eventName = 'success'
    GROUP BY events.userName, events.taskName
)
SELECT
    events.userName
    ,events.taskName
    ,COUNT(events.eventName) AS FailuresUntilFirstSuccess
FROM
    Successes
    LEFT JOIN events
        ON  events.taskName = Successes.taskName
        AND events.timestamp < Successes.FirstSuccessTime
        AND events.eventName = 'fail'
GROUP BY events.userName, events.taskName
;
```

Comment: In attempting to create a question with minimal, human-readable example data, I left out some data that I hadn't realized was relevant.
I've created a new question with better sample data:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675062/t-sql-count-number-of-failures-before-first-success-2

I'll keep this question as is, and will accept an answer that works with the original data and has syntax that Vertica understands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more solutions using `CTEs`. The idea is to receive min row with `success` first. After that we can filter out other rows using simple condition, like `row < min` per user:

```
DECLARE @events TABLE([row] INT,eventName VARCHAR(50),taskName VARCHAR(50),userName VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @events
        VALUES(1,'fail','ABC','John')
       ,(2,'fail','ABC','John')
       ,(3,'fail','ABC','Mike')
       ,(4,'fail','XYZ','John')
       ,(5,'fail','XYZ','Mike')
       ,(6,'success','ABC','John')
       ,(7,'fail','ABC','John')
       ,(8,'success','ABC','John')
       ,(9,'success','ABC','Mike')


SELECT * FROM @events;

WITH
    cte
    AS (
            SELECT userName
                    ,taskName
                  ,MIN(row) AS [min]
            FROM @events
            WHERE eventName = 'success'
            GROUP BY userName,taskName)
SELECT e.userName
        ,e.taskName
      ,COUNT(1) AS attempts
FROM @events e
JOIN cte c ON e.userName = c.userName
WHERE e.row < c.[min]
GROUP BY e.userName, e.taskName
```

Comment: Vertica gives me the following error: `ERROR: Cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement`

Comment: @AkiKanerva are you using my data to insert?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in converting to Vertica syntax. It executes now, but doesn't separate the results per task.

Comment: @AkiKanerva add groupping by taskName to achieve this. I'll update answer

Comment: Yes, the updated answer works! For reference, Vertica doesn't understand `@` notation for tables or the brackets around `[min]`. Leaving those out passes syntax check.

Comment: @AkiKanerva could you please mark answer as correct one?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server or Vertica, you can use window functions to count the number of successes before each row.  Then use that for aggregation:

```
select username,
       sum(case when success_cnt = 0 and eventName = 'failure' then 1 else 0 end) as numfailures_to_first_success
from (select e.*, 
             sum(case when e.eventName = 'Success' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by e.username order by e.row) as success_cnt
      from events e
     ) e
group by username;
```

Note:  If you want this per task, then include that in both the `partition by` and `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

> **Updated and Corrected - Missed userName**

Perhaps with a Cross Apply and a WITH TIES clause.

The top subquery will return only the first "success" records partitioned by taskName, and userName.  In this case, only row 6 would be returned.

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From (
        Select Top 1 with ties * 
         from YourTable
         Where [eventName]='success'
         Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By taskName,userName Order by [row])
      ) A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Cnt=count(*) 
                 From YourTable 
                 Where taskName=A.taskName and A.userName=userName and [row]<A.[Row] and eventName='fail'
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Vertica gives me the following error: `ERROR: Syntax error at or near "1"`

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Based on the schema, this query will give you what you want:

```
with Failures as
(
    select * from Event where event_name = 'fail'
),

Q as
(
    select * from Event E
        outer apply
        (
            select count(*) cnt from Failures F
                where F.task_name = E.task_name and F.username = E.username and F.ts < E.ts
        ) F

    where E.event_name = 'success'
)

select * from
(
    select Q.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by event_name, task_name, username order by ts) o from Q
) K where K.o = 1
```

Testing with your data yields:

```
id event_name task_name  timestamp  username  cnt
-- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---
6  success    ABC        25         John      2
```

But, I went a bit further and added another 'success' row for Mike

```
insert Event select 'success', 'XYZ', 29.0, 'Mike':
```

and get

```
 id event_name task_name  timestamp  username  cnt
 -- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---
 6  success    ABC        25         John      2
 9  success    XYZ        29         Mike      1
```

as expected.

#### Explanation

The first CTE generates a set of failures. The second CTE is recursive, where the base case is the set of successes and the recursive case is a count (cardinality) of the set of failures that preceded a given success (with respect to a user and task name).

Finally, we use `row_number` with respect to partitioning on `event_name`, `task_name` and `username`, so that the first success for a given partition will be labeled as '1'. Then we just filter out all of the rows whose `row_number` is unequal to '1'.

Comment: Excellent explanation for someone like myself who's still learning. However, Vertica gives me `ERROR: Syntax error at or near "outer"`

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution too:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.userName, T1.taskName)
FROM tbl AS T1
WHERE T1.row < (   SELECT MIN(row)
                   FROM tbl AS T2
                   WHERE T2.userName = T1.userName
                   AND T2.taskName = T1.taskName
                   AND T2.eventName = 'success');
```

Similar solution to Artem's, but slightly different. Subquery will find lowest row value for each user and task that succeeded and will filter row based on that.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easier way to get here, but I'll try to look more later.

Test Data Setup

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#taskevents', N'U') IS NOT NULL   
DROP TABLE #taskevents;  
GO  

CREATE TABLE #taskevents ( 
      eventName varchar(10)
    , taskName varchar(10)
    , ts decimal(3,1)
    , userName varchar(10)
) ;

INSERT INTO #taskevents ( eventName, taskName, ts, userName )
VALUES 
      ('fail','ABC','10.5','John')
    , ('fail','ABC','10.6','John')
    , ('fail','ABC','18.0','John')
    , ('fail','ABC','22.0','John')
    , ('fail','ABC','22.5','John')
    , ('success','ABC','25.0','John')

    , ('fail','ABC','26.0','John')
    , ('success','ABC','28.0','John')

    , ('fail','XYZ','10.7','John')
    , ('fail','XYZ','21.0','John')

    , ('fail','ABC','19.0','Mike')

    , ('fail','XYZ','23.0','Mike')
    , ('success','XYZ','28.5','Mike')

    , ('success','QVC','42.0','Mike')
;
```

Query Time

```
SELECT s3.userName, s3.taskName, AVG(s3.failCount) AS avgFailCount
FROM (
    SELECT s1.userName, s1.taskName, s1.ts, s1.PreviousTS, COALESCE(s2.failCount,0) AS failCount
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.userName, t1.taskName, t1.ts, LAG(t1.ts) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.userName, t1.taskName ORDER BY t1.ts) AS PreviousTS --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.userName ORDER BY t1.ts) AS rn
        FROM #taskevents t1
        WHERE t1.eventName = 'success'
    ) s1
    OUTER APPLY ( 
        SELECT t2.userName, t2.taskName,  COUNT(*) AS failCount 
        FROM #taskevents t2
        WHERE t2.eventName = 'fail'
            AND t2.userName = s1.userName
            AND t2.taskName = s1.taskName
            AND t2.ts < s1.ts  
            AND ( t2.ts >= s1.PreviousTS OR s1.PreviousTS IS NULL )
        GROUP BY t2.userName, t2.taskName
    ) s2
) s3
GROUP BY s3.userName, s3.taskName
```

That gives you the average failures per user.

Comment: That is MS T-SQL2012+ because of the LAG() window function. I'm not familiar with Vertica. I don't know if it has the same types of window functions or not. If so, that should put you on the right path.

Comment: Vertica supports LAG, but I get `ERROR: Syntax error at or near "OUTER"`

Comment: Does Vertica support OUTER APPLY? Or maybe a different syntax on using it? This is T-SQL format, so I'm not sure how that would translate to Vertica.

Comment: I don't think Vertica supports the APPLY statement. I can't find it in the manual, and I found a question where someone wanted to know the equivalent of CROSS APPLY in Vertica: https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/238031/equivalent-of-cross-apply-with-function-in-vertica

Comment: @AkiKanerva I posted another answer on the updated question that uses a LEFT OUTER JOIN and a CTE instead of the OUTER APPLY.

Comment: I'll link the new answer in case anyone else stumbles here first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681066/4354459