# T-SQL: Count number of failures before first success (2)

Tags: sql, t-sql, analytics, vertica

I have a DB with events for task attempts and their results (fail or success). For each user, I'd like to count the number of failures before the first success. Subsequent failures and successes shouldn't affect the output - I'm only interested in the first success of a given task. Also, the DB contains rows with other events that should be ignored.

How do I formulate this in T-SQL on a Vertica database?

(I would eventually like to calculate the average number of attempts per task, but let's keep that out of the scope of this question to keep things manageable.)

This is an update of the question here:
[T-SQL: Count number of failures until first success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638981/t-sql-count-number-of-failures-until-first-success)

In the original question, I'd given poorly constructed sample data which didn't fully reflect my use scenario, and led to answers that weren't applicable with my actual data and that I couldn't verify.

The solution shouldn't rely on row order - it's possible that rows aren't populated in timestamp order.

Here's the DB setup:

```
CREATE TABLE events {
      eventID int -- unused in this example, should be excluded from output
    , eventName varchar(256)
    , userName varchar(256)
    , timestamp timestamp
    , taskName varchar(256)
    , sessionID int -- unused in this example, should be excluded from output
};

INSERT INTO events
    VALUES
        (2363460186192576512, 'beginSession', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:46:46.712', NULL, 145031357)
      , (2363460852537008128, 'success', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:49:32.471', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363461162974437376, 'success', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:50:48.781', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363460390131740672, 'fail', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:47:37.349', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363460556662710272, 'fail', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:48:23.024', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363460730671505408, 'fail', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:48:58.646', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363461032111800320, 'fail', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:50:10.726', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363460389896859648, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:47:05.32', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363460463137751040, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:47:52.166', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363460556205531136, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:48:12.615', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363460692671205376, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:48:36.155', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363460852268572672, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:49:12.047', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363460962524327936, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:49:47.951', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363461162714390528, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 09:50:23.645', 'TaskOne', 145031357)
      , (2363474741421064192, 'beginSession', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:44:36.042', NULL, 145031392)
      , (2363474885491200000, 'success', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:45:14.577', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363475342389641216, 'success', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:47:04.098', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363475473998635008, 'success', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:47:34.135', 'TaskOne', 145031392)
      , (2363475822079254528, 'success', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:48:53.381', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363476096949104640, 'success', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:50:07.441', 'TaskThree', 145031392)
      , (2363475066098266112, 'fail', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:45:53.526', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363475195152531456, 'fail', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:46:32.81', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363475654638821376, 'fail', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:48:13.71', 'TaskThree', 145031392)
      , (2363476247751114752, 'beginSession', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:50:37.67', NULL, 145030476)
      , (2363476335819063296, 'success', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:51:06.841', 'TaskOne', 145030476)
      , (2363476485643796480, 'success', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:51:41.086', 'TaskTwo', 145030476)
      , (2363476806063038464, 'success', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:52:53.174', 'TaskTwo', 145030476)
      , (2363477266119335936, 'success', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:54:32.053', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363477619191631872, 'success', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:56:01.783', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363476705131655168, 'fail', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:52:21.312', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363476939634896896, 'fail', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:53:28.906', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363477390937976832, 'fail', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:55:05.499', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363476335592570880, 'beginTask', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:50:50.074', 'TaskOne', 145030476)
      , (2363476485501190144, 'beginTask', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:51:20.784', 'TaskTwo', 145030476)
      , (2363476704779333632, 'beginTask', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:51:54.829', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363476805752659968, 'beginTask', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:52:34.001', 'TaskTwo', 145030476)
      , (2363476939496484864, 'beginTask', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:53:06.468', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363477265938980864, 'beginTask', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:53:45.631', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363477390635986944, 'beginTask', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:54:44.706', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363477573427560448, 'beginTask', 'Mike', '2017-08-14 10:55:17.231', 'TaskThree', 145030476)
      , (2363474885214375936, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:44:44.702', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363474985177161728, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:45:31.133', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363475195014119424, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:46:10.098', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363475342184120320, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:46:45.357', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363475473616953344, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:47:17.911', 'TaskOne', 145031392)
      , (2363475654437494784, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:47:47.681', 'TaskThree', 145031392)
      , (2363475771776864256, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:48:27.1', 'TaskTwo', 145031392)
      , (2363476006456762368, 'beginTask', 'John', '2017-08-14 10:49:06.151', 'TaskThree', 145031392)
    ;
```

With this data, here is the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
userName  taskName   numFailuresBeforeFirstSuccess
John      TaskOne    3
John      TaskTwo    0
John      TaskThree  1
Mike      TaskOne    0
Mike      TaskTwo    0
Mike      TaskThree  3
```

Comment: Based on your data, shouldn't John have 4 failures before the  first success for `TaskOne`?

Comment: @RodrickChapman You're correct, that was a typo. Edited.

Comment: Looking through your data, here's what I'm seeing, in order. 
John - Task 1 = 3 Fail, 1 Success, 1 Fail, 1 Success, 1 Success. Task 2 = 1 Success, 2 Fail, 1 Success, 1 Success. Task 3 =  1 Fail, 1 Success. 
Mike - Task 1 = 1 Success, Task 2 = 1 Fail, 1 Success, 1 Fail, 1 Success, Task 3 = 2 Fail, 1 Success, 1 Fail, 1 Success.

Comment: Is that not the correct order? Did I miss something?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, I tripped over my own cleverness because the rows were out of order on purpose. There's a success between John's 3rd and 4th attempt on TaskOne. Everything in your comment is correct, except Mike's TaskTwo is 2 Success, no Fails.

Comment: @AkiKanerva That was my fault. I misread my own notes. :-S  
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
John    1 - 3|1, 1|1, 0|1 > 2 - 0|1, 2|1, 0|1 > 3 - 1|1 ////
Mike    1 - 0|1 > 2 - 0|1, 0|1 > 3 - 2|1, 1|1
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select e.username, e.taskname,
       sum(case when timestamp < first_success_ts and e.eventname = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) as numFailuresBeforeSuccess
from (select e.*,
             min(case when e.eventname = 'success' then e.timestamp end) over
                (partition by e.username, e.taskname) as first_success_ts
      from events e
     ) e
group by e.username, e.taskname
order by e.username, e.taskname;
```

This calculates the first success time using a window function.  This should work in both databases (as least in SQL Server 2012+)

Comment: Hmm... all results are 0 when I execute this query. The inner select seems to return correct minimum timestamps, so perhaps there's a quirk in comparing timestamps in Vertica? Trying to search the docs on that now...

Comment: This is strange. Trying to force it as `timestamp < first_success_ts::TIMESTAMP` doesn't work either. If I enter a static value, like `timestamp < '2017-08-14 10:54:32.053'` (one of the results returned by the inner select), I get non-zero results as expected.

Comment: `order by e.timestamp` in the inner select seemed to result in rows where first_success_ts was null. Removing it made it work, though I have no clue why. Do you know?

Comment: @AkiKanerva . . . Good catch.  There should have been no `order by` there for the logic at all.

Comment: For a novice like myself still struggling equally with many concepts of analytics, this answer was the easiest to comprehend and to use as a base for similar scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Once again, this is TSQL and not Vertica, but it's fairly standard SQL, as long as Vertica supports CTEs.

```
; WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT t1.userName, t1.taskName, t1.ts
        , LAG(t1.ts) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.userName, t1.taskName ORDER BY t1.ts) AS PreviousTS 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.userName ORDER BY t1.ts) AS rn
    FROM #taskevents t1
    WHERE t1.eventName = 'Success'
)
SELECT s1.userName, s1.taskName, AVG(s1.failCount) AS avgFailCount
FROM (
    SELECT cte1.userName, cte1.taskName , cte1.rn,  COALESCE(COUNT(t2.ts),0) AS failCount 
    FROM cte1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #taskevents t2 ON t2.userName = cte1.userName
        AND t2.taskName = cte1.taskName
        AND t2.ts < cte1.ts  
        AND ( t2.ts >= cte1.PreviousTS OR cte1.PreviousTS IS NULL )
        AND  t2.eventName = 'fail'
    GROUP BY cte1.userName, cte1.taskName, cte1.rn
) s1
GROUP BY s1.userName, s1.taskName
ORDER BY s1.userName, s1.taskName
```

This gives your averages. Remove the outer query to get the data that I'm working with. It produces slightly different results than what you had listed, but should give the proper average that you said you were looking for. Please let me know if I misunderstood the requirements.

NOTE: In my test data, I also added two individuals who had Fails with no success, just to verify that they were excluded from the results.

```
, (2363476006456762398, 'fail', 'Steve', '2017-08-14 11:29:06.151', 'Task42', 145031342)
, (2363476046456762368, 'fail', 'Joe', '2017-08-14 11:49:06.151', 'Task42', 145031399)
```

=====================================

RESULTS

```
-----------------------------------
|userName|  taskName |avgFailCount|
-----------------------------------
|  John  | TaskOne   |     1      |
|  John  | TaskThree |     1      |
|  John  | TaskTwo   |     0      |
|  Mike  | TaskOne   |     0      |
|  Mike  | TaskThree |     1      |
|  Mike  | TaskTwo   |     0      |
-----------------------------------
```

========================================================================

EDIT: For the Average by just the Task:

```
; WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT t1.userName, t1.taskName, t1.ts
        , LAG(t1.ts) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.userName, t1.taskName ORDER BY t1.ts) AS PreviousTS 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.userName ORDER BY t1.ts) AS rn
    FROM #taskevents t1
    WHERE t1.eventName = 'Success'
)
SELECT s1.taskName
    , AVG(CAST(s1.failCount AS decimal(5,2))) AS avgFailCount
FROM (
    SELECT cte1.userName, cte1.taskName , cte1.rn,  COALESCE(COUNT(t2.ts),0) AS failCount 
    FROM cte1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #taskevents t2 ON t2.userName = cte1.userName
        AND t2.taskName = cte1.taskName
        AND t2.ts < cte1.ts  
        AND ( t2.ts >= cte1.PreviousTS OR cte1.PreviousTS IS NULL )
        AND  t2.eventName = 'fail'
    GROUP BY cte1.userName, cte1.taskName, cte1.rn
) s1
GROUP BY s1.taskName
ORDER BY s1.taskName
```

Which gives you

```
--------------------------
| taskName  |avgFailCount|
--------------------------
| TaskOne   | 1.000000   |
| TaskThree | 1.333333   |
| TaskTwo   | 0.400000   |
--------------------------
```

Which is essentially

```
SELECT (3+1+0+0)/4.0  AS TaskOne
SELECT (0+2+0+0+0)/5.0 AS TaskTwo
SELECT (1+2+1)/3.0 AS TaskThree
```

Derived from the following data points.

```
--------------------------------
|userName|  taskName |FailCount|
--------------------------------
|  John  | TaskOne   |    3    |
|  John  | TaskOne   |    1    |
|  John  | TaskOne   |    0    |
|  Mike  | TaskOne   |    0    |
|  John  | TaskTwo   |    0    |
|  John  | TaskTwo   |    2    |
|  John  | TaskTwo   |    0    |
|  Mike  | TaskTwo   |    0    |
|  Mike  | TaskTwo   |    0    |
|  John  | TaskThree |    1    |
|  Mike  | TaskThree |    2    |
|  Mike  | TaskThree |    1    |
--------------------------------
```

This is an average number of Fails before a Success, not the average number of Fails per attempt. That would be slightly different.

```
---------------------------------------------------
| task | fails | attempts | avg fails per attempt |
---------------------------------------------------
| Task1|   4   |    8     | 4/8 = 0.500000        |
| Task2|   2   |    7     | 2/7 = 0.285714        |
| Task3|   3   |    7     | 3/7 = 0.428571        |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: FYI: #taskevents is my temp table name for your events table.

Comment: Syntax appears to work in Vertica and results look good. The average I was looking for was actually "average attempts until first success per task", not per user. So, if in TaskOne John had 3 failures before success and Mike had 0, the average would be 1.5. Looking at my original wording that wasn't super clear though.

Comment: If you remove t1.userName from the SELECT, GROUP and ORDER, it will give you the average you're looking for. Also CAST s1.failCount as a decimal datatype, and it should break it down to decimal averages.

Comment: Do you mean s1.userName, not t1? This seems to give me different results than @Gordon Linoff 's method when I wrap it in avg(). The averages with your method are 0.4, 1.0, 1.333, when they should be 0.0, 1.5, 2.0.

Comment: Sorry, yes remove s1.userName. I was using "t" for Table and "s" for SubQuery. I apparently typed my response too fast.

Comment: I think Gordon's might be slightly different because it's looking for the _first_ failure by UserName, and mine is looking for the number of failures before each success. So Gordon's factors 1 Success for username John on TaskOne, and mine factors in 3 Successes for John on TaskOne. Slightly different math involved, so it depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the ambiguity in my question, thanks for explaining! I'm only interested in what each user does before succeeding for the first time. On a conceptual level, this query is for measuring how users learn unfamiliar tasks, rather than repeating familiar tasks. So for this particular analysis, all events after the first success should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
 with F as
 (
    select *  from Evts where eventName = 'fail'
 ),

 S as
 (
    select * from Evts E 
        cross apply
        (
            select count(F.eventID) numFailuresBeforeFirstSuccess from F 
                where F.userName = E.userName and 
                      E.taskName = F.taskName and 
                      F.timestamp < E.timestamp
        ) K

    where eventName = 'success'
 )

 select userName, taskName, numFailuresBeforeFirstSuccess from      
    (select *, row_number() over (partition by userName, taskName order by [timestamp] desc) o from S ) S 
       where o = 1
```

yields this result:

```
userName    taskName    numFailuresBeforeFirstSuccess
----------- ----------- -----------------------------
John        TaskOne     4
John        TaskThree   1
John        TaskTwo     2
Mike        TaskOne     0
Mike        TaskThree   3
Mike        TaskTwo     0
```

The [previous explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638981/t-sql-count-number-of-failures-until-first-success/45641044#45641044) applies here.

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/PNZTT50840)

Comment: It seems that Vertica doesn't support the APPLY statement. I can't find it in the documentation, and there's a question (unanswered) on the equivalent of CROSS APPLY in Vertica: https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/238031/equivalent-of-cross-apply-with-function-in-vertica

Comment: @AkiKanerva -- It looks like Vertica does support `CROSS APPLY`: 
 https://my.vertica.com/get-started-vertica/working-with-joins/, but the syntax is different. I think that we just need to figure out how to do subqueries in Vertica.

Comment: Hmm... I'm still getting `ERROR: Syntax error at or near "OUTER"` with your query.

Comment: @AkiKanerva - Try changing it to `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: This time it's `ERROR: Syntax error at or near "apply"`. My kingdom for better error messages...

Comment: Unless CROSS APPLY behaves differently in Vertica, it isn't quite what's need. CROSS APPLY (like an INNER JOIN) will remove rows where an OUTER APPLY (like a LEFT OUTER JOIN) won't. So it may require reordering the query.

Comment: @Shawn -- Yep. This solution *did* use `OUTER APPLY` (see edit history). But since it looked like Vertica didn't  support it, I suggested the `CROSS APPLY`. If that had worked, then I would have tried recovering the the lost rows with another join. N.B. I did use `OUTER APPLY` for a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638981/t-sql-count-number-of-failures-until-first-success/45641044#45641044) from the OP.

Comment: Does Vertica support both CROSS and OUTER APPLY? I guess I don't really see why it wouldn't. It's really the an APPLY with a difference in how the data joins.

Comment: @Shawn -- When I first read the [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/get-started-vertica/working-with-joins/), I thought that it supported `CROSS` but not `OUTER` (which I thought was strange); now  that I read it again, it looks like it does not support `APPLY` at all. But, I'm not familiar with that system.

Comment: @RodrickChapman Gotcha. I'm not familiar with it either, but I would hope that a database designed for analytics would have something that functions like an APPLY. That makes things so much easier. :-)